# The Best tool for building Sencha (Ext JS) applications are?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I started working on Ext JS, but the building process has always been a headache to me as I always used notepad..

Can you suggest some tools which help me build the Ext JS applications easily....

Comment: Have you tried Notepad++?  It may not be a full-featured IDE, but it's a much better code editor than plain old Notepad.

Comment: @PrateekRaj : Do you know questions asking for a tool or library are off-topic on Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Initial GUI Setup (if you're feeling lazy!)

[Ext Designer](http://www.sencha.com/products/designer/)

IDE for further development

[Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio2) or [CodeRun (online)](http://www.coderun.com/studio/) or [eCoder (online)](http://ecoder.gmeditor.com/)

Bug testing during development

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Debugging the final layer of polish

[YSlow for Firebug](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)

Comment: CodeRun seems to be a bit patchy, an Internal Error message keeps appearing when I try to sign up.

Comment: is there a way to use eclipse? if so, explain briefly. i already visited many blogs and tried to setup eclipse but failed..!

Answer (score 1):

I'm usually a fan of Eclipse, but Check out PHPStorm, it has better colouring, works well with libraries and does refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio2) + [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Plus a handset of each type you intend to code for.

Also, see this link for an answer to a similar question: 
["Debugging" ExtJS script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067709/debugging-extjs-script/4069980#4069980)

Answer (score 0):

TextMate? It's really a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Textpad - I've been using it for 12 years now.

Answer (score 0):

**Spket IDE** is powerful toolkit for working with JavaScript Framework like extjs.
You can also use **Eclipse and Spket plugin** for developing better javascript code. Visist http://www.spket.com/ for more details.