# Does ext-all-debug.js really work?

Tags: extjs, extjs6.2

After changing ext-all.js into ext-all-debug.js, the data grid couldn't load data for both version 6.0.0.640 and 6.2.0.981. Does ext-all-debug.js really work? What is the way to debug extjs?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067709/debugging-extjs-script

Comment: If "the data grid doesn't work", you should find an error message in browser console.